# 'Variable' variables not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

im practicing javascript .

and im trying using array element as array name in Javascript .

i searchd stackoverflow and found some links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

when im testing this i found that its not working, it gives undefind when im calling the second function. please see the [jsbin link](https://jsbin.com/yazowutera/edit?html,output) 
, maybe im getting it wrong please help me out.
here is my code , and link: [https://jsbin.com/yazowutera/](https://jsbin.com/yazowutera/edit?html,output)

```
<button onclick="testArrays1(a, [vic.zero, vic.one])">source</button>
<br>
<button onclick="testArrays2(a, vic[all[1]])">desti</button>
```

and javascript

```
<script>

var vic = {

    zero : ["00","01","02"],

    one : ["10","11","12"],

    two : ["20","21","22"]

};
var all = ["zero","one","two"];

var a = "a";


function testArrays1(needle, arrays){
    for (var i=0; i<arrays.length; i++) {
        alert(needle +arrays[i]);
    }
}

function testArrays2(needle, arrays) {
  //for (var i=0; i<arrays.length; i++) {
    alert(needle +arrays);
  //}
}

</script>
```

im not in j-query right now please ans in javascript

Comment: who should i mark the right answer because all are right answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `all` is a special variable reserved for [`HTMLAllCollection`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/common-dom-interfaces.html#htmlallcollection-0) and the second element of it (i.e. `all[1]`) is a HTMLHeadElement. This only seems to applicable when working with inline scripts (scripts in element attributes). It seems you have to do `document.all` if using normal script blocks (but this may be caused as a side-effect of testing with JSFiddle).

The recommended solution is to use a different variable name. For example, change the variable to `test`:

```
<button onclick="testArrays2(a, vic[test[1]])">desti</button>

var test = ["zero","one","two"];
```

Comment: where can i find list of all these reserved things because  i wasted 2  hours for finding this cheap solution

Comment: I wouldn't concern yourself with a list. Just learn how to debug your issues better. A simple `console.log(all)` would have shown you that something was wrong with `all`, then a quick search would have got you the answer. Try to avoid using inline scripts, create a `script` block and register your button clicks in that - though you will want to do it on document ready (or equivalent)

Comment: thnx for the tip, have you own any website or blog or something online , where you post about programing.

Comment: @victor: Sorry I don't. I just try to help on here when I get the chance

Answer (score 1):

"all" (or "document.all") is a reserved variable that returns an HTMLAllCollection. Change your variable name to something else in your javascript and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

As metioned by others **all** is a reserved keyword. But if you still want to use it you can use as below. Which works!

**Remember: Always using a reserved keyword as variable in JavaScript coding is a bad practice. So refrain using those reserved words.**

Your Javascript:

```
window.all = ["zero","one","two"];
```

Your HTML:

```
<button onclick="testArrays2(a, window.all[1])">desti</button>
```

Comment: where can i find all reserved keywords list for future use